# Azure AD Access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I just started working with Azure Active directory and i have one simple query.

I have a customer who is the admin of azure subscription and now if he wants to give access to another user who will be tasked to Create and Managing of **Azure Active Directory** (Like adding/deleting users, providing access to other application) what level of Role/permission needs to be assigned to this user.

Please let me know the steps for doing this from portal or any reference link please share

Answer (score 0):

For just user management an "User Administrator" role would be sufficient. As far as the applications go it may vary depending on the level of access required and so on.

Check out the Azure AD roles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-roles).

But at the subscription level it is better that the user has an "owner" role which provides all the administrative privileges.